# Keep relative cursor position after indenting with >>

Tags: indentation, cursor-movement

Can I setup `>>` to keep the relative cursor position?
For example, assuming the line is

```
def fun(<cursor>):
```

can I make `>>` result in

```
    def fun(<cursor>):
```

?

Obviously, with `set startofline`, the cursor goes to the beginning of the line after indenting. 
But even with  `set nostartofline`, the cursor moves erratically,  and changes both its relative position within the line as well as its absolute position in the line, depending on how the line looks like.

[image]

Comment: the cursor does not change position. It stays exactly at its same position. However, since the line changes, it looks like it moved.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt For me the cursor does change both absolute and relative position with both `startofline`(obviously) and `nostartofline` (unexpectedly) , see the screencast in the updated question.

Comment: you might check before and after the cursor position using `:echo getpos('.')`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I don't understand what you're getting at. Clearly, the cursor does not stay at the colon in the screencast (relative position) and it does not stay at column 10 (absolute position) as confirmed by the statusline and eyesight.

Comment: well, please show the output of `getpos('.')` before and after indent!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt before first indent: `[0,1,10,0]`; after first indent: `[0,1,3,0]`; after second indent: `[0,1,2,0]`. Just to be clear: If vim's technical definition of "cursor position" conflicts with that of someone ignorant of vim internals, I obviously am concerned with the latter. No technical discussion of cursor positions will change the fact that my cursor does not stay where it is relative to the line content (also not absolute in terms of column numbers, but that I don't really care about)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let me first explain, what is happening here.

When indenting lines, Vim will indent the line, which means depending on the 'shiftwidth', 'tabstop', 'expandtab' and possibly also the 'vartabstop' options determine whether to insert leading tabs or blanks into the line. When the 'startofline' option is at its default value, the cursor will be moved to the first non-blank on the line.

The interesting thing is what happens, if the 'startofline' option is switched off. Well, basically the cursor stays at the exact same position, as it was before something was inserted. But since shifted right, the cursor appears to move. Now remember, that depending on a bunch of options, several blanks might actually be replaced by a single tab, so that technically the byte column might even decrease(!), while the line still appears to be shifted to the right.

You can verify this, by comparing the output of `:echo virtcol('.')` before and after you have (de-)indented your line.

So according to the documentation, the line will always be shifted by the amount of `shiftwidth()` spaces. So you need to adjust the cursor position (but not the byte column). This can be done like this:

```
func! Indent(ind)
  if &sol
    set nostartofline
  endif
  let vcol = virtcol('.')
  if a:ind
    norm! >>
    exe "norm!". (vcol + shiftwidth()) . '|'
  else
    norm! <<
    exe "norm!". (vcol - shiftwidth()) . '|'
  endif
endfunc

nnoremap >> :call Indent(1)<cr>
nnoremap << :call Indent(0)<cr>
```

This will map the `<<` and `>>` in normal mode to perform the normal `<<` and `>>` comamnds and will afterwards re-adjust the cursor positioning. 
Error management, range handling and handling e.g. visual mode has been intentionally left out. Those cases should probably be handled if a plugin is made out of it.